# Regular expression to only extract CSS class names before {display:none}

Tags: php, regex

I can't find a correct regular expression to extract classes names.
It is my code:

```
preg_match_all('@\.(.*!\.){display:none}@', '.UlEa{display:none}.RNLW{display:inline}.jc0k{display:none}.Lyhf{display:inline}', $matches);
```

The $matches is empty.
How should look correct regular expression?

Comment: Try [`'@\.(\w+){display:none}@'`](https://regex101.com/r/oaaH1X/1). Why did you use `!`?

Comment: Thx, it works. When I didn't used  `!` function returns me 1 result: `UlEa{display:none}.RNLW{display:inline}.jc0k{display:none}.Lyhf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your regex matches a literal `.`, then captures a sequence of any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as many as possible up to the last `!.` sequence and then matches `{display:none}`. Since your text does not contain `!` nor the next `.` you have no match.

One way to get your matches is to use `\w+` (=one or more word characters, those in the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` set) pattern inside Group 1:

```
\.(\w+){display:none}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oaaH1X/1)

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Yl6oiP):

```
preg_match_all('@\.(\w+){display:none}@', '.UlEa{display:none}.RNLW{display:inline}.jc0k{display:none}.Lyhf{display:inline}', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); // => Array ( [0] => UlEa [1] => jc0k  )
```

Comment: However it's not OP's requirement, may you add a version to capture all class names / ids before a CSS body? +1

Comment: @revo: Once you provide test cases for that, sure. Also, try [`'@\.([^{.]+){display:none}@'`](https://regex101.com/r/oaaH1X/2).

Comment: [Here you are.](https://regex101.com/r/oaaH1X/3) To capture all ids / class names before a CSS block declaration.

Comment: @revo: There is only one CSS block that has `{display:none}` and it matches correctly. That means it is already a different question that you may ask as a separate one. Also, you have not mentioned what exact values you need to extract from that string.

Comment: Whatever CSS block contains is not important. Just all ids and class names before each single block. Like `id-name` as an id, `class-name` and `jc0k` as class-names for the first block and `id-name-two` as an id for the second one. I saw the title of this question very relevant so I thought it could be great if you expand the scope of the answer to cover most possible cases (for future reference) that not only extracts class-names but also ids.

Comment: I see, however, that is already beyond the scope of this very answer. If the title is misleading, it is best to adjust it to the real task OP has. As for *generic* CSS parsing, I'd recommend a dedicated library, something like http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1289-PHP-CSS-parser-class.html or https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser.

Comment: No I actually didn't mean a parser although they exist. That's fine if you don't think it's relevant to this.

Comment: @revo: If you want to talk that over, consider joining the [RegEx - Regular Expressions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex-regular-expressions) chat, or ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. I will join the chat but not for this reason since for it I had a purpose.